# MOSFET Level Shifting 3.3V to 5V Floating

Tags: mosfet, logic-level

I have an XBEE chip that requires 3.3V logic levels and I'm having it talk to an ATMEGA328P that uses 5V logic (atleast in my application). I added in a MOSFET level shifting circuit to shift between the two bidirectionally. I don't need bidirection shifting but it should still work the same. I copied the circuit from [here](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Logic_Level_Bidirectional.pdf) using a BSS138 MOSFET.

The problem I'm facing is the output to the Low Voltage side is staying somewhat constant around 3.3V but switching between 0V and 5V still as shown by the output shown from my oscilloscope.

[image: Oscilloscope output from LV Serial Line (RX from HV shown)]

Does anyone have any idea what would cause this? I copied the circuit from the sparkfun link exactly and still no luck. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: To add a little more context, here is a piece of our schematic (ignore the bad layout, this was done quickly to get the boards produced fast). VCC is 5V and the mosfet is connected to the 3.3V regulator shown below as VREG2. The XBEE is shown partially at the bottom of the image and the ATMEGA is off to the right where the highlighted line runs.

[image]

UPDATE 2: Per requested, here are images of the footprint and schematic views from Solidworks as well as the footprint from the datasheet for reference.

Schematic:
[image]

PCB Footprint from Solidworks:
[image]

Mosfet Layout from [DataSheet](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BS/BSS138.pdf):
[image]

Comment: "the **output to** the Low Voltage side is staying somewhat constant" - shouldn't that be the **input from** the low voltage side? (DOUT is an output from the XBEE).

Comment: Phillip - Can you please add either a photo straight down onto the PCB showing that MOSFET and the PCB tracks around it, or add the equivalent part of the PCB layout image?

Comment: "Ignore the bad layout"....  Suggestion:  If you want your boards done... and working... as fast as possible, spend a few more minutes making your schematic readable.  Once you do, you may find the problem becomes more obvious!

Comment: @bruce My bad, I highlighted the wrong trace. The one I’m testing with is going to DIN on the XBEE so it is the output.

Comment: @SamGibson I can, but I don’t think it’ll add too much value. That area of the board is pretty busy so it might be more confusing. Are you trying to see which pins I’m attached to on the device itself? I could upload the schematic and part views from the library if that would work as it would be clearer?

Comment: @PhillipMcMullen - Hi, (a) OK, let's try it a different way. How do you know that you have the MOSFET source & drain connected the right way round on your PCB? The "0, 1, 2" designations on the schematic don't tell me which *physical* pins on the BSS138 MOSFETs they actually refer to. Please add your evidence that physical MOSFET 0=G, 1=S, 2=D (b) You have 2 MOSFETs on the schematic snippet, performing level shifting. Based on your reply to *Bruce*, I assume that `Q1` connects to XBEE `DIN` (shifting only HV to LV) and `Q2` connects to `DOUT` (shifting only LV to HV). Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson Please see my update above. And that is correct, `Q1` is connected from `ATMEGA DOUT (HV)` to `XBEE DIN (LV)` and `Q2` is connected from `ATMEGA DIN (HV)` to `XBEE DOUT (LV)`. Also, thank you for the help.

Comment: @PhillipMcMullen - Thanks for that. I agree schematic seems to match correct pinout. I don't see how you can get the 5V pulses shown on your scope, on the LV (3.3V) side of that MOSFET, if it has correct source-drain polarity :-( From a troubleshooting point of view, my approach would need more details, further tests, probably some soldering etc. and this site is not well-suited to long troubleshooting threads. So it's best for me to pause here; perhaps someone else has easier tests or even an answer. Sincere good luck :-)

Comment: "My bad, I highlighted the wrong trace. The one I’m testing with is going to DIN on the XBEE so it is the output."  - _if_ that is true then either your MOSFET is broken or you have a wiring error. Remove the FET and wire a diode between pins 1 and 2 (Anode on pin 1). What happens?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I will give that a shot tomorrow once I'm back in the office. Thanks for the tip to test. Thanks SamGibson as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I'm posting the answer to this in hopes that it saves someone else a headache...

The MOSFETs were fine, my 3.3V regulator was to blame for the data level inaccuracy. As you can see in the scope image below, the 3.3V signal on the top was peaking to 5V before the 3.3V regulator picked up properly and regulated down to the 3.3V level. What I did to fix this was I added a 4.7UF capacitor on the output of the 3.3V regulator to buffer the power. I had a cap added in my schematic but, in my infinite wisdom, I left it off on the test board as I thought "this isn't needed for testing, I'm good".
[image]

After the cap was added, here was the result:
[image]

The 3.3V signal is on top while the 5V signal is on the bottom.

Thanks to everyone that helped, I truly appreciate it.